# How do I find out the serial port name logitech extreme 3d pro joystick on mac osx?

Tags: macos, serial-port, joystick, logitech

I want to find out the serial port name of a logitech 3d pro in order to be able to read the values from it.
I tried `<ls tty*>` then plugging in the joystick the `<ls tty*>` again to find out the extra name. However it doesn't show up.

The joystick is recognized in the  `-system report - hardware - usb -`. However it  only shows the `location ID`.

Is there is another way to find out the serial port name ? Or to connect to a port using the `location ID` ?
Thanks.

Comment: It's doubtful that this joystick would use a traditional serial port.  Are you sure it's not HID?